# How to calculate current value for DOUT and RIN pin in MAX3221E texas IC?

Tags: current, rs232, texas-instruments, ferrite-bead

Hi Im going to use ferrite bead in the Dout and Rin pin in MAX3221E IC of Texas. How to determine current rating of the pins , thereby i can choose the current rating of ferrite bead??

Comment: I'm fairly sure (having checked your site history) that you are not aware of the customs on this site so, [take the 2 minute tour](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand the motivation behind folk giving their free time to help you. Consider this retrospectively to your previous 6 questions too. Obviously, those that are not adequately answered don't need any action.

Comment: For what purpose do you want to use ferrite beads to begin with? RS232 comms are already slew rate limited.

Comment: selva97 - are we done here? Can we close this Q and A session down now or, do you have some residual comments that need clarification?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [data sheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/max3221e.pdf?ts=1627976212920&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F#:%7E:text=The%20MAX3221E%20is%20a%20single,%2D4%2D2%20ESD%20protection.&text=These%20devices%20operate%20at%20data,%C2%B5s%20driver%20output%20slew%20rate.) you'll get short circuit currents for the driver output pins: -

[image]

So, I'd be considering rating the FB in accordance with that.

For the receiver input, the current will be a few milli amps and not worth considering given that the output short circuit current of the driver is much higher and should be used as the basis for choosing the FB.

Comment: Microamps? More like between 0.4 to 8.3 milliamps, e.g 3 to 25 volts into 3 to 7 kohm load at the receiver input. But yes, maybe not worth considering. Unless a short circuit needs to be considered.

Comment: @Justme yes, that is true, I shall amend.